# Error: Abnormal build process termination in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

This week I updated Android Studio to version 2.0. There is a [known issue](http://tools.android.com/knownissues#TOC-Gradle-Sync-Failed:-Broken-Pipe) concerning Gradle, so I added `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true"` to my ~/.profile (on Ubuntu 15.10).

But now I get this error when compiling:

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true
Build process started. Classpath: /opt/android-studio/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/ecj-4.4.jarError connecting to ::1:44484; reason: Protocol family unavailable: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:44484
java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:44484
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:210)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:207)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1208)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeConnectNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:117)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeConnect(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:248)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:218)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeConnectNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:117)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeConnect(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:248)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:218)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeConnectNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:117)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeConnect(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:248)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:218)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:212)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Do you try the opposite flag _`JAVA_OPTIONS = -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` ?

Comment: Yes, I replaced the _JAVA_OPTIONS line in my ~/.profile by `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false"`. Now it seems to work but I don't know if this causes other problems. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the opposite flag `_JAVA_OPTIONS = -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`