# when building android project then error comes up related to jdk

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java" -Xmx1024m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=5087408374975979908 XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Djps.file.types.component.name=FileTypeManager -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=IN -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.2 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\deepak.AndroidStudio2.2\config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\deepak.AndroidStudio2.2\config\plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/deepak/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/log/build-log -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/deepak/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/compile-server/*temp* -classpath "C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/ecj-4.5.2.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/oromatcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/netty-all-4.1.0.CR7.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/openapi.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/rt/jps-plugin-system.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/asm-all.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/snappy-in-java-0.3.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/jsr166e.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/picocontainer.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-cli-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-logging-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-core-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-groovy-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-process-services-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-resources-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-2.14.1.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/jna-3.2.7.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/kryo-2.22.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/minlog-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/reflectasm-1.07.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/groovy-all-2.4.6.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/gson-2.5.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 49871 d703689d-d7ad-44f3-9373-b89a2f83eb0b C:/Users/Sharad/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/compile-server

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675753/error-abnormal-build-process-termination-in-android-studio-2-0

Comment: where i have to use  _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: Set Java path for your system correctly

Comment: i already set the java path... still facing problem

Comment: just try to kill awt from task manager and restart it.

Comment: are you using windows or ubuntu machine?

Comment: sachin@ window machine

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem...

Android Support plugin was not enabled... so  Just enable Android Support plugin.

[In android studio,cannot load 2 facets-unknown facet type:android and android-gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560746/in-android-studio-cannot-load-2-facets-unknown-facet-typeandroid-and-android-gr)